# Google maps undefined error

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Geocoder' of undefined

From this page:
http://comehike.com/draggable_marker.php

from this line of code:
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I loaded the page I did not get the Geocoder error in either Chrome or Firefox. Instead I got an error stating that in line 108 of draggable_marker.php that initialize was not defined. It looks like you are missing the braces after initialize in line 108.

Perhaps

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

should be

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```